# jQuery Dialog, how to bind a window resize event but only while the dialog exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery UI modal dialog. I want the dialog to be fixed positioned in the middle of the screen and on browser resize for the position to auto-update. It turns out this is not available by default.

So what I have done is:

```
dialog = $('<div id="dialog-content" class="ui-dialog-container"></div>').html('<div class="loading">Loading...</div>').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    position: ['center', 130],
    open: function() {

        // Fixed Positioning
        $('.ui-dialog').css({position:"fixed"});

        // Reposition on Window Resize
        $(window).resize(function() {
            console.log('resizing);
            $('.ui-dialog').dialog("option", "position", "center");
        });


    }
});
```

Notice the:

```
            console.log('resizing);
```

The problem here is that while this work,s when the dialog is closed the resizing event is still firing. How can I make this a binding that is associated with the dialog so that when the dialog is destroy the binding is also destroyed?

Thanks

Comment: Do your users seriously resize windows that often? :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to unbind the resize event when the dialog closes:

```
.dialog({
    ...,
    open: function() {
        ...
        $(window).bind('resize.dlg', function() {
            ...
        });
    }
    close: function() {
        $(window).unbind('resize.dlg');
    }
});
```

Comment: I need the resize event for other app related events. Just not for this dialog?

Comment: I do have the need for other resize events

Comment: As I said, look at my updated answer - it should now only unbind the correct resize event.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your dialog options:

```
close:function(){
    $(window).unbind('resize');
}
```